# "megahit: command not found" after correct installation with miniconda

Tags: assembly

I want to use `MEGAHIT` (git: https://github.com/voutcn/megahit) to assemble metagenome shotgun sequencing reads (illumina).

I install the package with the command `conda install -c bioconda megahit` as described in on the github page which yields:

```
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/datura-workstation/miniconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - megahit


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  megahit            bioconda/linux-64::megahit-1.2.9-h8b12597_0


Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Where I click yes and the packages is installed. However, after installation I am not able to use the command `megahit` as this results in the error: `megahit: command not found`.

I use Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and have installed `miniconda3`.

I reproduced the installation of `megahit` on a windows computer with a virtual machine using the same Ubuntu version. On my virtual Ubuntu I CAN use the `megahit` command.

Could anyone please help me solve this problem? I searched the internet but cannot find a good solution on the issue (also not on the github issue page of this package).

Comment: Why not just install Anaconda3?

Comment: Did you install conda without any custom modifications? Check the bin folder of the miniconda root folder for presence of the executable. If it is there then add the bin to PATH.

Comment: /home/datura-workstation/miniconda3/bin/megahit ? it should be there

Comment: Did you run `make install` after building?

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez Anaconda is a package manager that replaces compilation. Therefore this is not necessary. This must be a PATH or environment problem

Comment: @ATpoint Ah, gotcha. Thanks

Comment: In ```minconda3/bin``` there is no executable file named ```megahit```. (I checked the folder on my test virtual machine and there the file is indeed there.) That seems to be the problem. I can find the ```megahit``` on my workstation in the directory ```/home/datura-workstation/miniconda3/pkgs/megahit-1.2.9-h8b12597_0/bin```. Why is it there? Can I just copy these files to the ```miniconda/bin```?  All files of ```megahit``` are placed in this directory while they should be located in the ```miniconda3/bin``` directory.

Comment: EDIT: I re-installed ```megahit``` and now there the ```megahit``` files are present in the ```miniconda3/bin```. However, I still receive the error.

Comment: EDIT2: after activating ```conda activate base```, ```megahit``` became functional. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type `conda info --envs`.  Look at your list of environments.  Say it's `base` that has `megahit` in it, do `conda activate base`, then just do `megahit`.

Comment: even in the ```base``` environment, the command ```megahit``` is not found.

Comment: I re-installed ```megahit``` and now when I activate ```conda activate base```, ```megahit``` does work. Thank you!!